Version 3.6.3 in R not running ANY code on Mac
I'm having to run a bit of code in R 3.6 because of a package update, but when I switch my R to 3.6.3, no code will run. It's like Rstudio is stuck. I just simply wrote
x <- 10

to see if Rstudio would save that into the environment, but nothing is happening. 
I tried switching the version using Rswitch, and also the terminal, but both ways result in Rstudio freaking out on me. Any idea why it just won't run anything? This is my version of Rstudio: Version 2023.12.1+402 (2023.12.1+402)
Help is appreciated.

Are you able to use R version 4.3.3 instead?

@stefan_aus_hannover R version 4.2.3 works perfectly on my computer and that's normally what I use. I need to use R version 3.6.3 for a certain step of my analysis.

A lot of people have issues using the newest version of RStudio with older versions of R. The RStudio forum maybe helpful also trying to get a solution. https://forum.posit.co/

What happens if you just run R3.6.3 from the console? What Mac are you using? Your R3.6.3 seems to be compiled for intel, is it compatible with your architecture or is rosetta2 not running?

Yes, don't use RStudio.  Just use R.app if you really need to run R 3.6.3, but even better:  stay with a recent version.  If some package requires R 3.6.3, then run away from that package:  it will cause you a lot more grief.
